# How come when I query SQL data into R, the column names are changing?

Tags: sql, r, odbc, amazon-redshift

I am querying a table from SQL into R using the 'odbc' package. When I do so, some of the column names are being read in incorrectly.  Why would this happen? I've tried probably a dozen different fixes and nothing is working. Any ideas? My SQL table is in Redshift, if that helps at all.

For example, I have a column in the SQL table called 'gross_margin' and it is being read in as 'gross_marginf'. I have another column called 'foot_traffic' and it is reading in as 'foot_trafficm'.

Comment: Can you give any example of the code you use right now? It's hard to help if you do not provide any examples.

Comment: Welcome to SO, jacob fishback! Questions on SO do much better if they are reproducible; the [tag:sql] tag can be difficult (no access to your database), but there are several techniques to fill out the question to best inform the discussion (see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/3358272 for "reproducible SQL questions"). At a minimum, please show minimal code you attempt and a summary of the resultset you get from the query. Thanks!